# Migrating a native app to a RN/Expo app: keep user authenticated

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I want to migrate an existing Android+iOS native app to a react-native Expo app.

In current native app, we store an auth token. I'd like this auth token to be available through ReactNative `AsyncStorage` api out of the box, without requiring RN native code (ie, ejecting Expo).

Is this possible, in current native app, to start writing to the same place as AsyncStorage will read after the migration?

We aim for the smoothest transition from native app to RN app, and user should stay authenticated after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're current app is using for storage. I recently used this library (https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-default-preference) to get the data from user defaults then move it into async storage. I only migrate the refresh token and auth token.

If they are using core data, then you'll need to setup the same models etc - https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/584
The other storage mechanisms you can easily find a native package to get the data.

Answer (score -1):

if the app is under same app name scheme you may be able to access after upgrade i guess.